# Restart self-hosted WCF after invoking Process.Start from WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, process, process.start

I need to start processes from WCF service (self-hosted). I've done it by using Process.Start() method. Then I try to restart my WCF service and it fails because its address was already in use (but old process are not exist). This issue is similar with https://superuser.com/questions/215351/how-do-i-kill-a-process-that-is-dead-but-listening, and the exact problem related to processes opened from WCF service (they hold tcp connection opened). Is there any way to restart WCF service without restarting processes, started from this service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found only one way to start processes from WCF service safely. I have created a proxy process that is starting another processes and instead of starting specified process directly, first I start ProcessStarter.exe process which in its turn starts specified process and then it is closing. 
I can't explain Windows behaviour, but in this case all TCP connections created by WCF service will be closed.